# How do I convert a table of numbers to a list of numbers in excel?

Tags: excel

How do I convert this table of numbers to a list that goes from top to bottom.

[image]
Like this:
[image]

---

ERROR:
[image]

Comment: Best way to do this is to copy all of the other columns below each other, then just sort it ascending... Not rocket science...

Comment: What if I have 100 columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a very easy formula; [SMALL](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-small-function). This can return the nth smallest value in a give matrix/array.

As per given example, step by step:

- Define your matrix. You can choose any matrix, like `$A$1:$CV$10`, but in this example we will use `$A$1:$E$10`. The `$` makes this matrix absolute which means it won't change when we drag a formula down.
- Choose any cell you want to start your list. There are two options:

  - **1)** You start a list on the top cell of a column. In this case you can use:

    ```
    =SMALL($A$1:$E$10,ROW())
    ```
  - **2)** You start a list on any other cell. In this case you can use:

    ```
    =SMALL($A$1:$E$10,ROW(A1))
    ```
- And drag down.... You can see I used option 1.

  [image]
- If you want, you can extend the range as much as you like, e.g.: `$A$1:$CV$10`.

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic, What exactly is the problem? 'I can't get this to work' is not much to go by for me.

Comment: You see the block of numbers up there? I want all of those numbers to be placed in one column from top to bottom. like the one you made. I just don't get how you did it. Where can I read about this more in depth?

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic, see edited answer. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: When I do what you're telling me I get this error: see the OP.

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic Maybe your system uses a semicolon as seperater? Try a `;` instead of the comma. Also, when you press `OK`, what part of the formula is highlighted by Excel? As that usually gives a good indication what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the to.column function in Excel. It takes as input a range and returns a column.